# Lost password to ZIP file created with Gnome Archive Manager

Tags: password-recovery, archive, zip, rarcrack

I've lost the password to a zip file that was created under Unity, Nautilus file manager, which uses Ubuntu's Gnome Archive Manager (I must have mis-typed it when re-encrypting.)

It seems that `rarcrack` and `fcrackzip` don't seem to be compatible with the files produced by Gnome Archive Manager.  They both run but never seem to find the password, even when I create a test zip and use a simple and limited namespace.

I've had this problem a couple of times.  (I know I know, I should've learnt from my experiences.)

Does anyone have any more suggestions on such password recovery?

Comment: **If cracking a password was easy there would be no point in using passwords.** I don't know how the tools you used work but I suppose they try brute force. Depending on the encryption used it can take up to MILLIONS of YEARS with the computational power of a super-computer.

Comment: I know, I'm not stupid.  A limited namespace cuts the time down dramatically though.  The problem is frcrackzip and rarcrack DON'T WORK on files created with Gnome Archive Manager (i.e. created with Unity/Nautilus.)  To check this, I created a test file with the linux command line zip (Info-ZIP 3.0) using a similar password then tried cracking that with the limited namespace, which worked.  I then changed the file using Gnome Archive manager and ran it through the same fcrackzip and it exhausted the namespace without any matches.

Comment: Archive Manager or any other similar GUI tool in Linux does nothing by itself. They all are frontends. The actual *magic* is done by CLI tools which are the same whether you use Archive Manager, ARK (KDE/Kubuntu) or any other. By default there's support for most of the compress file types, rar and 7zip have to be installed but once installed are called and used by the GUI tool.

Comment: You can download a fast Windows zip cracker and run it with Wine.  Install Wine with `sudo apt-get install wine`.