# fcrackzip - Incompatibility with Gnome Archive

Tags: gnome, archive, rarcrack

This was experienced by somebody else in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939325/lost-password-to-zip-file-created-with-gnome-archive-manager#new-answer)  not well documented old thread.

The tool to brute force passwords work properly when a zip file is created from the command line. Here is a test result for a file named testfile.txt encrypted using password 'pass'.

```
kannamma@dink:/media/kannamma/drives/PC/TestRun$ zip --password pass locked.zip testfile.txt
  adding: testfile.txt (deflated 13%)


kannamma@dink:/media/kannamma/drives/PC/TestRun$ fcrackzip -b -c 'a' -l 4 -u -v locked.zip
found file 'testfile.txt', (size cp/uc     84/    83, flags 9, chk be51)


PASSWORD FOUND!!!!: pw == pass
kannamma@dink:/media/kannamma/drives/PC/TestRun$
```

However, instead of the command line, if the file is encrypted using Gnome archive manager, fcrackzip is unable to find the password. Here is the test result.

```
kannamma@dink:/media/kannamma/drives/PC/TestRun$ fcrackzip -b -c 'a' -l 4 -u -v lockedwithGnome.zip
found file 'testfile.txt', (size cp/uc     92/    83, flags 1, chk 0000)
kannamma@dink:/media/kannamma/drives/PCrack/TestRun$
```

Why fcrack zip is incompatible with Gnome Archive Manager. What difference does it make to the file if it is encrypted using command line instead of Gnome Archive Manager?

Comment: Are you sure that the file lockedwithGnome.zip is password protected at all ?

Comment: Yes. I have myself archived it with password.